# Adobe Flash CS6 AS3: KeyUp Handler triggers immediately after KeyDown Handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So in my code I was attempting to make it where you had two players, each player had their own key down and key up handlers, clearly labelled in my attached code, and in their I handle the movement, player one has WSAD and player two uses the Left, Right, Up and Down keys, however, when ever I press the relative key down handler, it immediately fires the key up handler straight after, and I do not know why, here is my code, if anyone could help that would be great! :)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    var playerOneLeft:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerOneRight:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerOneUp:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerOneDown:Boolean = new Boolean(false);

    var playerTwoLeft:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerTwoRight:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerTwoUp:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    var playerTwoDown:Boolean = new Boolean(false);

    var playerSpeed:int = 5;

    var gamePage:GamePage;

    public function Main(){
        gamePage = new GamePage();
        addChild(gamePage);
        addAllPlayerHandlers();
    }

    public function playerOneKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A){
            playerOneLeft = true;
            trace("a");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.D){
            playerOneRight = true;
            trace("d");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.W){
            playerOneUp = true;
            trace("w");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.S){
            playerOneDown = true;
            trace("s");
        }
    }

    public function playerOneKeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A){
            playerOneLeft = false;
            trace("a");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.D){
            playerOneRight = false;
            trace("d");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.W){
            playerOneUp = false;
            trace("w");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.S){
            playerOneDown = false;
            trace("s");
        }
    }

    public function playerTwoKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            playerTwoLeft = true;
            trace("left");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            playerTwoRight = true;
            trace("right");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            playerTwoUp = true;
            trace("up");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            playerTwoDown = true;
            trace("down");
        }
    }

    public function playerTwoKeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            playerTwoLeft = false;
            trace("left");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            playerTwoRight = false;
            trace("right");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            playerTwoUp = false;
            trace("up");
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            playerTwoDown = false;
            trace("down");
        }
    }

    public function playerMovementHandler(event:Event):void{
        if(playerOneLeft){
            gamePage.playerOne.x -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerOneRight){
            gamePage.playerOne.x += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerOneUp){
            gamePage.playerOne.y += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerOneDown){
            gamePage.playerOne.y -= playerSpeed;
        }

        if(playerTwoLeft){
            gamePage.playerTwo.x -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerTwoRight){
            gamePage.playerTwo.x += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerTwoUp){
            gamePage.playerTwo.y += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(playerTwoDown){
            gamePage.playerTwo.y -= playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    public function playerOneCollision(event:Event):void{
        if(gamePage.playerOne.hitTestObject(gamePage.leftWall)){
            gamePage.playerOne.x += playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerOne.hitTestObject(gamePage.rightWall)){
            gamePage.playerOne.x -= playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerOne.hitTestObject(gamePage.topWall)){
            gamePage.playerOne.y -= playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerOne.hitTestObject(gamePage.bottomWall)){
            gamePage.playerOne.y += playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerOne.hitTestObject(gamePage.middleWall)){
            gamePage.playerOne.x -= playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    public function playerTwoCollision(event:Event):void{
        if(gamePage.playerTwo.hitTestObject(gamePage.leftWall)){
            gamePage.playerTwo.x += playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerTwo.hitTestObject(gamePage.rightWall)){
            gamePage.playerTwo.x -= playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerTwo.hitTestObject(gamePage.topWall)){
            gamePage.playerTwo.y -= playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerTwo.hitTestObject(gamePage.bottomWall)){
            gamePage.playerTwo.y += playerSpeed;
        }
        if(gamePage.playerTwo.hitTestObject(gamePage.middleWall)){
            gamePage.playerTwo.x += playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    public function addPlayerMovementHandler(){
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,playerMovementHandler);
    }

    public function addPlayerKeyHandlers(){
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,playerOneKeyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,playerOneKeyUpHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,playerTwoKeyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,playerTwoKeyUpHandler);
    }

    public function addPlayerCollisionHandlers(){
        gamePage.playerOne.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,playerOneCollision);
        gamePage.playerTwo.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,playerTwoCollision);
    }

    public function addAllPlayerHandlers(){
        addPlayerKeyHandlers();
        addPlayerCollisionHandlers();
        addPlayerMovementHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when ever I press the relative key down handler, it immediately fires the key up handler straight after

This is because you registered them as

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,playerOneKeyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,playerOneKeyUpHandler); // this is for type KEY_DOWN, but the handler is "Up"
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,playerTwoKeyDownHandler); //that looks suspicious, too
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,playerTwoKeyUpHandler);
```

The lesson you should learn is that your copy & paste approach to writing code is a bad practice. You should not repeat yourself. All this duplicated code leads to problems like the one at hand.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I copy and pasted due to the fact that it was mostly similar, but I forgot to check over properly, thank you! :)

Comment: Even more amazing is the fact that a 2 seconds check would suffice to see the error, instead he chose to come spend 2,3 minutes typing his question here.

Comment: Well, if you had bothered to read my comment instead of wasting 30 seconds typing that response, you would suffice to see I had pointed that out, and stated I incorrectly checked it over ;)

Comment: @BrentHogeling And you should also mark this answer as 'correct'.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking how to do so, which admittedly took me a while, but I will do now! :)